# How to return asynctask result to result of method that called it in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a method that should return a long value. Within this method, there is an asyncTask that inserts the information into the room database. How can I send the asyncTask return value as the result of the same method that I called it ?!

Public long insert(MyTask task){
.
.
.
return /* result of AsyncTask */
}

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with `Thread` or `AsyncTask`, you cannot use their result as a return of the method that starts them.

Results of `AsyncTask` are handled by `onPostExecute`.

You can override the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask`. Then process your result there.

```
class MyAsyncTask {
    void onPostExecute(long result) {
        // process the result here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I want add data into room database and I want to show the user a notification in specific time. and for this task I need this id. What is your suggestion to get this id?

Comment: `result` is the id from `doInBackground`, where you added the data into room. You can create the notification inside `onPostExecute`